# get data from one of 5 objects at random

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having trouble with my code. I have 5 objects and I want to randomly pick one of the object and get the data from it. I can call data from one of the objects with `c1['cn']` so I thought if I pick a number from 1 to 5 and replace the number with the random one that it would call the data from that object.

```
var ram = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) +1);
var ref = 'c' + ram;
console.log(ref['cn']);
```

the console.log is saying 'undefined'

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

you can see my code in the code snippet.

```js
function cardsLab (cname, dis, t1, t2, t3){
 this.cn = cname;
 this.d = dis;
 this.s1 = t1;
 this.s2 = t2;
 this.s3 = t3;
}
var c1 = new cardsLab('card No1', 'blar', 8, 5, 10);
var c2 = new cardsLab('card No2', 'blar', 6, 10, 9);
var c3 = new cardsLab('card No3', 'blar', 7, 5, 3);
var c4 = new cardsLab('card No4', 'blar', 10, 4, 9);
var c5 = new cardsLab('card No5', 'blar', 8, 6, 7);


var ram = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) +1);
var ref = 'c' + ram;
var x = ref+"['cn']";
var z = x;
console.log(x);
console.log(ref['cn']);
console.log(c1['cn']);
```

Comment: try `window[ref]['cn']` or `this[ref]['cn']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off putting all the cards in an array.  It makes it much easier to reference them dynamically.  It even means you can use the `.length` property to count them, rather than needing to hardcode the number 5.

Like this:

```js
function cardsLab (cname, dis, t1, t2, t3){
 this.cn = cname;
 this.d = dis;
 this.s1 = t1;
 this.s2 = t2;
 this.s3 = t3;
}
var cards = [];
cards[0] = new cardsLab('card No1', 'blar', 8, 5, 10);
cards[1] = new cardsLab('card No2', 'blar', 6, 10, 9);
cards[2] = new cardsLab('card No3', 'blar', 7, 5, 3);
cards[3] = new cardsLab('card No4', 'blar', 10, 4, 9);
cards[4] = new cardsLab('card No5', 'blar', 8, 6, 7);


var ram = Math.floor((Math.random() * cards.length));
var x = cards[ram];
console.log(x);
```